# Use non-exportable Windows store private key in openSSL

Tags: c++, openssl

I'm using OpenSSL in C++ under Windows to implement an SSL client. So my goal is to use a certificate installed in the certificate store to do the handshake with the server.

Now, the problem is that as the private key is non-exportable I can't use it directly in a call like `SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey`.

So far I tried to use the CAPI engine to do the handhshake, but I haven't figured out how to set the private key in the SSL context.

Thanks

Comment: In the simplest case, you don't need any keys or certificates to act as SSL/TLS-client.

Comment: I know, but in this case the server only allows to connect if the client has an authorized certificate

Comment: When a private key is non-exportable you can't export the private key, you can only use it with the windows crypto api.  So there is no way to import the private key into openssl.  So to use a windows cert store private key into openssl you have to export the private key then import it into openssl.

Comment: My answer here may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55148179/23235